# Proof of Elementary Resulting Concerning Finite Set Cardinality

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Is the following Proof Correct?

**PLEASE READ NOTE BELOW BEFORE READING PROOF**

**Theorem.** If $n\in\mathbf{N}$ and $A\subseteq I_n$, then $A$ is finite and $|A|\leq n$.

**Proof.** For the purpose of clarity let us restate the statement above as follows.
$$\forall n\in\mathbf{N}\forall A(A\subseteq I_n\implies \exists m\in\mathbf{N}(A\thicksim I_m)\land |A|\leq n)$$

We construct the proof by recourse to *Mathematical-induction.*

For $n = 0$. Let $A$ denote an arbitrary subset of $I_0$, it must be that $A = \varnothing$ since $\mathcal{P}(\varnothing) = \{\varnothing\}$, consequently $\varnothing\thicksim I_0$ implying $|\varnothing|\leq 0$.

Now let $k$ be an arbitrary natural number and assume that
$$\forall X(X\subseteq I_k\implies \exists q\in\mathbf{N}(X\thicksim I_q)\land |X|\leq k)$$
Assume further that $A$ is an arbitrary subset of $I_{k+1}$, now consider the following cases.

*Case-1($k+1\not\in A$):* Since $k+1\not\in A$ it stands to reason that $A\subseteq I_k$ and thus by use of the inductive-hypothesis above it follows that for some $q\in\mathbf{N}$, $A\thicksim I_q$ implying that $A$ is finite and $q = |A|\leq k$, by extension it follows that $|A|\leq k+1$.

*Case-2($k+1\in A$):* Since $k+1\in q$ it follows that the set $G = A\backslash\{k+1\}\subseteq I_k$ consequently by use of the inductive hypothesis above it follows that for some $q\in\mathbf{N}$, $G\thicksim I_q$ and $q = |G|\leq k$.

Evidently $G\cap\{k+1\} = \varnothing$ and $\{k+1\}\thicksim I_1$ thus by appealing to theorem **$7.1.7$** it follows that 
$$|A| = |G\cup\{k+1\}| = |G|+|\{k+1\}| = q+1$$
but $q\leq k$ consequently $|A| = q+1\leq k+1$.

$\blacksquare$

NOTE: Preliminary Information

$I_n = \{i\in\mathbf{Z^+}|i\leq n\}$

$A\thicksim B\Leftrightarrow$ There is a bijection from A to B

A is finite $\Leftrightarrow\exists n\in\mathbf{N}(A\thicksim I_n)$

**Theorem $7.1.7$** Suppose A and B are disjoint finite sets. Then $A\cup B$ is finite,
and $|A \cup B| = |A| + |B|$.

Comment: The first $<$ of the theorem is supposed to be a $\le$ and the $\subset$ is supposed to be a $\subseteq$.

Comment: Sorry let me correct it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, that works. A couple notes:

- If you want to make it a bit easier on yourself, you could prove $|A|\leq n \implies (\exists m \in \mathbb{N} )A \thicksim I_m$
- Set quantification is implicit in naive set theory, you probably don't need to write it down. Kudos on keeping track of all your variables, though!
- What about trying a proof by contradiction? Suppose $|A| > n$, how would that affect the bijection function, and the function invariants of the subset relation? Sometimes, you'll find that the proof may be a lot easier if you try a different tactic.

Comment: Oh WOW so many ideas that i didnt think of . Thank you very much !